# PHP call all XML nodes objects without mentioning child node name

Tags: php, xml, loops

```
<Node name="node1">
  <x x="x"/>
  <x x="xxx"/>
</Node>

<Node name="node2">
  <x x="xx"/>
  <x x="xxxx"/>
</Node>
```

Okay, this is an XML sample:

I call its content using simplexml_load_file

and if i wanna call a specific node content it should be :

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('file.xml');
$contents = $xml->node1
```

and to call node object

```
$contents = $xml->node1->x
```

Seems fine till now,
the question is,
how to call object "x" without mentioning node name

you noticed the sample i added above it has 2 nodes

to call x from it i should mention nodename then x

i want to call all "x" from the whole XML

how is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SimpleXMLElement::xpath() will do the trick when you don't have namespaces to worry about.  If you do have namespaces... you'll need SimpleXMLElement::registerXPathNamespace().

```
<?php
$xml = <<<EOT
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<root>
<Node name="node1">
  <x x="x"/>
  <x x="xxx"/>
</Node>

<Node name="node2">
  <x x="xx"/>
  <x x="xxxx"/>
</Node>
</root>
EOT;

// Original question
$s = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$r = $s->xpath('//Node/x');
var_dump($r);

// Something about names
$r2 = $s->xpath('Node[@name]');
$names = array();
foreach($r2 as $elem){
  $names[] = "{$elem['name']}";
}
var_dump($names);

// RoseWarad's answer (more efficient than "something about names")
$r3 = $s->xpath('*/@name');
var_dump($r3);

?>
```

Comment: While you're at it, here's more xpath to play with: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev

Comment: what if i wanna select all node names without x?

Comment: This will get you all elements with a "name" attribute equal to "node2".  Also, in this case, you'll get all the sub-nodes too (which you can ignore or process at your discretion). $r = $s->xpath('*[@name="node2"]');

Comment: No, i mean, how to get names of all nodes like i did with x, so it ends up with Node1, Node2 WITHOUT including x or any of its children

Comment: [misread your edited comment] Since you changed your comment's question... I dunno... Get all nodes, get all nodes including "x"... do a diff, and then you'll have those without "x"?  It's a (relatively) costly/heavy thing to do.  I don't know if SimpleXMLElement::xpath does advanced xpath 2.0 expressions... and I wouldn't know the necessary expression... but maybe someone else here would...

Comment: The other slightly tricky thing with SimpleXMLElement results is that you tend to have to cast things to strings by shoving the results into double-quote-plus-brackets.  Kind of like the names thing I added to the code answer.

Comment: hm, not sure if you got what i mean but there i am again, i want to select all nodes normally xpath("/*") and exclude x from them, so, only nodes without children